# Custom Linux AMI: How does AWS know where to install account SSH .PEM files when an AMI is provisioned?

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys, amazon-ami

We are building a custom AMI from a template EC2 EBS instance snapshot (Oracle Linux 8). This page shows there are many different user names depending on the AMI you choose:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html#ami-default-user-names

So, when we create the AMI template, does the `ec2-user` need to be created so that AWS will install the selected keypair `.pem` file into `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Ultimately my question is this:

- What tells Amazon where to install the account's ssh `.pem` key when an AMI is provisioned?
- Do we get any control over how the AMI is provisioned with respect to initial SSH access?

Comment: SSH is started with `-o AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/share/ec2-instance-connect/eic_run_authorized_keys %u %f -o AuthorizedKeysCommandUser ec2-instance-connect`. Perhaps that gives you the info?

Comment: @Halfgaar, good point, maybe.   What package provides `/usr/share/ec2-instance-connect/eic_run_authorized_keys`?  (use `dpkg -S <path>` or `rpm -qf <path>` depending on your OS)

Comment: You mean you don't have that package? It's `ec2-instance-connect`.

Comment: You can also provide 'user data' to launching an instance, which is a script it runs. You could just generate any `authorized_keys` with it if you want.

Comment: @Halfgaar, I'm building a vanilla non-ec2 image and then ec2ifying it... so I don't have the package as its not packaged with Oracle Linux (or at least, not out of the box)